# Elixir Installation on ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install **elixir** on my **ubantu 20.04** but i am constantly getting error.
I have used this article. 
[Elixir installaton-1](https://r00t4bl3.com/post/how-to-install-elixir-on-linux-mint-20-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa)

1. please guide my how can i install elixir on my system.
2. why it is necessary to install Erlang before installing elixir.
3. and please explain me the complete installation process sequentially. with full discription of each step why we are doing these step.

error message :-

```
bishen@b:~$ sudo apt install esl-erlang elixir
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package esl-erlang
```

Comment: What error did you get? Please post the detailed error message

Comment: i have added the error message. i am beginner to elixer. so can you please explain me the the points i asked.

Comment: The guide you linked is for Ubuntu 16.04 server. I wouldn't expect it to work for Ubuntu 20.04, the first step is to check prerequisites which is the step you obviously missed.

Comment: ok, but now i used another article for (ubuntu-20.04) but still getting error. changed the article link and error message. have a look.

Comment: Well the package `elixir` is in Ubuntu repositories for 20.04. But you spelled it differently here. If you spell things incorrectly in your terminal, you will not achieve the desired result. It's also incredibly important that you spell things (especially commands) correctly when asking for help here. It's essential that the details you put in your question are accurate, otherwise it's extremely difficult for us to audit your actions. Can you tell us why you need this other package? The directions you linked use it for Mint, which is not Ubuntu. Make sure you also follow directions correctly

Comment: @Nmath 1) sorry for the spelling mistake, it will not happen in future again, though english is not my first language.  2) i think the direction i linked is for for both mint and ubuntu 3) i didn't understood your question `Can you tell us why you need this other package?` what other package??

Comment: `sudo apt install esl-erlang elixir` is the command you are running.  `elixir` is the package you are asking about and it is in repositories. All you ever needed was `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt install elixir`. `esl-erlang` is the "other package". It's also the one giving you an error because it is *not* in Ubuntu repositories. But you're only asking us how to install elixir. So do you need this other package for whatever you plan to do with elixir?

Comment: Reading that blog post myself, I don't blame you. The instructions are really not clear at all. I find that blog posts can be unreliable: they are often outdated, they may contain errors, and the author may not be knowledgeable or authoritative.  Instead, it looks like the people responsible for maintaining elixir actually have their own documentation. When available it's usually best to follow documentation straight from maintainers or developers. See: https://elixir-lang.org/install.html#gnulinux -- According to their docs, you need to add a repo/source to install esl-erlang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Method 1

First follow the following article to install Erlang. 
[Erlang install](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/downloads/)
and then install Elixir: `sudo apt-get install elixir`

---

### Method 2

Here are the [official](https://elixir-lang.org/install.html#gnulinux) installation instructions.

Download .deb file of erlang-solutions, which will automatically add a repository to your system.

```
wget https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang-solutions_2.0_all.deb
```

Now install it.

```
sudo apt install ./erlang-solutions_2.0_all.deb
```

Update the software sources.

```
sudo apt update
```

Now install erlang and elixer.

```
sudo apt install esl-erlang elixir
```